# How to use symfony3 web services to send notification to ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, symfony-3.3

I'm new on symfony and i would make connection between symfony3 web-services  and ionic application to send notifications.

Can you guide me solving this please?

I had tried with fcm bundle but it not work for me.

Thanks in advence.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but **you need to help yourself first**. :-) After doing more research if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).